# How to mix all products in the cart into 1 product in woocommerce cart?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have cart widget on the right side with individual item,
I would like to mix all of the individual item into one Mix item when 'Mix' button is call with 'Mix name' input field like in the picture:

> So Before 'mix',

Every product in the cart is an Individual product
the cart will detect item and restriction for item that belong to which category - so based on restriction, only max 9 items can be in the cart at this time.

> when user hit mix:

every individual product in the cart will merge into 1 Mix product with including product name for each, product quantity for each, product price total

[image]

Comment: Have you found solution about this one ? I'm looking for it to ...